# Add collaborators to AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to add other users to your AWS account? Or do you have to share credentials? We have a business account that has all of the funding information, and I, as the developer, need access to set everything technical up.

Answer (score 4):

Most definitely you can. You need to set up users in the [IAM (Identity and Access Management) console](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/).